Problems when using ai_query function in Azure Databricks with serverless SQL warehouse in us-east
I am trying to run a very easy test with ai_query to access llama2 in Azure Databricks, basically I am just executing this query given in the documentation:
SELECT ai_query(
   "databricks-llama-2-70b-chat",
  "Can you explain AI in ten words?"
 )

I am running this on a SQL serverless size S in a region with full support: useast. I am getting this error:
[UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE.AI_FUNCTION] The feature is not supported: AI function ai_query is only available in Interactive Workloads, Jobs, SQL Pro and SQL Serverless, or it's disabled explicitly.
As i am running on a SQL Serverless it makes me think it is "disabled" but I have no idea how to activate this. In the documentation is pretty clear that it is not needed to enroll for this feature:
From the documentation: "Querying Foundation Model APIs is enabled by default. To query endpoints that serve custom models or external models, you must enroll in the public preview"
has anybody faced the same error?

I found the problem, when creating the new sql serverless you need to specify "preview" in the advanced options
